# If you know how to get JSON working with Rails 3.2, can you figure this out?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json

I'm trying to build a dynamic menu so when the user selects a country, the state menu is updated.

I'm looking at my dev logs and I see that the action runs the db query and then renders the json.erb file, but I can't get any response from the browser.

Here's what I have:

**controllers/settings_controller.rb**

```
respond_to :html, :json

  def getstates
    @states = Country.find_by_iso(params[:account][:addresses_attributes]["0"][:country]).states
    respond_with(@states)
  end
```

(Note: The form is a nested form, that's why the params hash is so long.)

---

**settings/edit.html.erb**

```
<%= address.collection_select :country, Country.order(:name), :iso, :name, {:include_blank => true}, "data-remote" => true, "data-url" => "/settings/getstates", "data-type" => :json  %>

<%= address.select :state, [], {:include_blank => true}, :disable => true %>
```

---

**settings/getstates.json.erb**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#account_addresses_attributes_0_country").bind('ajax:success', function(evt, data, status, xhr){
      var select = $('#account_addresses_attributes_0_state');

      if (data !== null) {
        select.removeAttr('disabled');
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
          $("<option/>").val(value[1]).text(value[0]).appendTo(select);
        });
      } else {
        select.empty();
        select.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      }
    });
});
```

(Note: I got this code from http://blog.madebydna.com/all/code/2011/12/05/ajax-in-rails-3.html)

---

**Dev logs**

```
Processing by SettingsController#getstates as JSON
  Parameters: {"account"=>{"addresses_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"country"=>"UY"}}}}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
  Country Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "countries".* FROM "countries" WHERE "countries"."iso" = 'UY' LIMIT 1
  Rendered settings/getstates.json.erb (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 3ms (Views: 1.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

This is the output I see in my dev logs.  But nothing in the browser.  I've tried adding alerts and console log methods, but nothing.

I'd really appreciate if someone could help me understand what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Firebug's console tab, you'll see the ajax request be made.  Then you can open it up and see the response body.  Like Ryan has suggested you're requesting JSON but returning full javascript. So if you were to keep it that way you'd have to eval the response in your callback function i.e. eval(data)  or jQuery also has a shortcut where you can request a 'script' type;  But it's kinda frowned upon now that RJS has been removed from Rails.  Instead do as Dan has suggested, move the contents of settings/getstates.json.erb into your edit view, and delete the getstates.json.erb file.  To aid you in making this work make the request/response simplier for now. Just do this and inspect it in Firebug to see what's happening.  After which, hook it up to turn the response contents into the option tags you're wanting.

```
$.get("/settings/getstates", function(data){
  console.log(data);
}, 'json')
```

Comment: Sweet, it worked!  I had to modify the URL to include the params needed for the controller action to find the states, but it returned a set of JSON objects to the console!  Next question... how do I access them now?  As the very least, I'd like to see them in the view just as a check, but ideally, I want to insert them into the states selector in my address field.

Comment: FYI, after some tinkering, I figured out how to grab the json and get the JS to do what I needed with it.  Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

First, I'm a little confused about your .json.erb view. It looks like you're returning Javascript (to execute in the browser) when the REST request is asking for JSON.

Secondly, I'd take a look at your favorite [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) alike tool (be that Chrome's Developer Tools or Safari's... whatever. Take a look at what's coming back from the AJAX request you're making to the server. (Maybe it's not what you expect - either an error code or you're getting something different from what you - or the `collection_select` expects).

My guess is that your .json view is spitting back actual Javascript, which then (something) tries to parse as JSON, fails and gives a Javascript error message somewhere (aborting the Javascript). Again, easiest way to track down one of those is with a Firebug-alike.

Comment: That's the problem, I'm not seeing anything in the browser console.  If I do a standard js request, I can see the browser respond, but there's no feedback, errors, logs.  Also, forgive me but, what did you mean by: `irst, I'm a little confused about your .json.erb view. It looks like you're returning Javascript (to execute in the browser) when the REST request is asking for JSON.`

Comment: Nathan, JSON is not Javascript. Put the contents of getstates.json.erb into a javascript file then delete it. respond_with(@states) will render the @states array as JSON.

Comment: In other words, rename the getstates.json.erb to getstate.js.erb?  I've tried that but then I don't see the server logs rendering the file.

Comment: Is there a good way to catch what's coming back from the controller during the reply so I can see the collection?  I've been working in the dark.

Comment: I think Firebug's Net tab will do this - any request made including Ajax requests will show up, including the body of the response. I know Chrome's Web Developer tools do this (I do most of my dev work in Chrome - and it has this behavior -, so thus the uncertainity).

Comment: When renmaning the file you won't see the server logs trying to render the file, because (my hypothesis is that) rendering that file is wrong in this situation: that file renders javasscript, not JSON. Imagine if you ordered a burger at a restaurant and they gave you a Philly Cheesesteak. It's "almost but not quite" what you wanted - I think the same thing is going on here: something wants JSON back and you're giving it Javascript to execute.

Comment: I finally did get it to work, but it took understanding how to view the logs in the browser console.  Just starting out at this, I didn't know how to send requests via the console to see what the response would be -- so I was just shooting in the dark.  Thanks for your help.